# How to prevent recursive page loading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, iframe, content-management-system

I'm trying to do something fancy.
I want an admin interface for a site to be available on every page as a side loaded spa.
I want to conditionally switch the layout in such a way that when 'admin' is logged in, then site contents are loaded into iframe (so it can be navigated independently).

for example in layout.cshtml

```
@if(admin) {
    <!-- admin layout -->
   <iframe src="@thisPageUrl"/>
   <div>admin interface bootstrap</div>
}else{
   <!-- regular layout -->
   <head></head>
   <body>@RenderBody()</body>
}
```

And admin interface is bootstrapped in some div which can be activated separately from site content.

Now first problem I see is that when admin is logged in and we decide so based on IsInRole() or some other user property and load requested page in iframe, then we will get a recursive page, because the cookie will not change for second request.

Maybe admin layout should be turned on by a request parameter. But then it sort of defeats whole point of admin interface being available at any given time on every page.

I'm looking for ideas.
Bring it on.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea my colleague got is to serve a preview site from another domain name. And for requests to that address - disable logins and cookies in general.